# rake-pipeline: How to append coffeescript files after jquery?

Tags: javascript, rake, assets, pipeline

Consider the following folder full of javascripts I want to compile into a single one using `rake-pipeline`:

- jquery.js
- some-jquery-plugin.js
- yet-another-jquery-plugin.js
- library-1.coffee
- library-2.coffee

`library-1` and `library-2` depend on jQuery.

### Assetfile

```rb
require "rake-pipeline-web-filters"

output "dist"

input "js" do
  match "**/*.coffee" do
    filter Rake::Pipeline::Web::Filters::CoffeeScriptFilter
  end

  match "**/*.js" do
    filter Rake::Pipeline::Web::Filters::UglifyFilter
    filter Rake::Pipeline::OrderingConcatFilter, ["jquery.js", "libs/ufvalidator.js"], "application.js"
  end
end
```

I have noticed that when concatenating everything, the scripts written in Coffeescript are at the top. Won't `OrderingConcatFilter` prevent this from happening? What should I fix so that the Coffeescript source is after jQuery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The UglifyFilter renames the files it processes to add a `.min.js` suffix. `jquery.js` goes into uglify, `jquery.min.js` comes out.

I would probably put the UglifyFilter last, like this:

```
match "**/*.js" do
  concat ["jquery.js", "libs/ufvalidator.js"], "application.js"
  uglify
end
```

but you could also change the filenames you're matching with the ConcatFilter:

```
match "**/*.js" do
  uglify
  concat ["jquery.min.js", "libs/ufvalidator.min.js"], "application.js"
end
```

or tell the UglifyFilter not to rename the files:

```
match "**/*.js" do
  uglify { |input| input }
  concat ["jquery.js", "libs/ufvalidator.js"], "application.js"
end
```